# Offset spline vectors each on his own origin. (Animation Nodes)

Tags: animation-nodes

I would like to replicate an animation as we can see here below with AN;

https://twitter.com/archillect/status/1068306137341194250

however I have difficulties to displace from each vector origin. Resulting in something like below.

[image]

Is it possible to have a offset according to each vector position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the nice things about circles is that their points' locations are also the normals at those points. So simply scaling a circle's points locations based on frequency bins and adding that to the location gives you what you want:

[image: Node Tree]